# How to block access to "cloud app" via Microsoft 365

Tags: windows-defender, microsoft-365

So my company is using **Microsoft 365** (E5 license). And we're leveraging "Microsoft Defender Cloud App Catalog" to block access to some "cloud apps".

However, it turned out that some people actually need access to the blocked cloud apps, which is doable using Defender's "Device Group".

Unfortunately, it seems **one endpoint device can only be a member of exactly one Device Group, no more, no less**.

That led me to set things up like this:

[image: Venn Diagram of 2 sites access]

Once I created the 3 Device Groups, on the "Unsanctioned" setting of Site A, I excluded the "CanA" and "CanAB" groups. Similarly for Site B, I excluded "CanB" and "CanAB" from the site's "Unsanctioned" settings.

Everything works acceptably, as expected.

However, it came to pass that there is now a THIRD site that needs similar treatment. This means the relation is now like this:

[image: Venn diagram of 3 sites access]

This is such a complexity! Not to mention that if in the future a fourth site needs the same treatment, the number of groups will grow out of control.

Is there a better way to leverage Microsoft 365 to provide what I want?

(If a device can be a member of multiple device groups, of course this is easily solvable. But the fact is, a device can only be a member of exactly one device group.)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Microsoft Entra/Azure AD Conditonal Access. In CA (Conditonal Access) you can add multiple groups as exclusion

Edit/Update

If the app doesn't exists you need to create an app manually

Here is an PowerShell script which checks if the app exists and if not creates the app and then creates the policy

```
# Install the required module if not already installed
Install-Module -Name Az -Force -AllowClobber

# Connect to Azure AD
Connect-AzAccount

# Define variables
$appName = "TelegramWeb" # You can change this to a suitable name
$identifierUri = "https://web.telegram.org/"
$application = Get-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName

# Check if the application exists
if (!$application) {
    # Create the application
    $application = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName $appName -IdentifierUris $identifierUri
}

# Get the application ID
$applicationId = $application.ApplicationId

# Create Conditional Access policy to block Telegram Web
New-AzAdPolicyConditionalAccessPolicy -Name "BlockTelegramWeb" -State "Enabled" -UsersAll $false -UsersIncludeGroups @("Group1", "Group2") -ApplicationsIncludeApplications $applicationId -GrantControlsIncludeGrantControls @("BlockAccess") -SessionControlsIncludeSessionControls @("UseConditionalAccessAppControl") -AccessControlsIncludeAccessControls @("Block")
```

Comment: I tried using CA, but when I reached the "Target Resources" step, the sites to block are not listed in the "Select" substep.

Comment: You don't select sites but select the cloud apps (which are enterprise applications in entra) (Under Target resources > Cloud apps)

Comment: That's the problem. The apps I'm trying to block are not listed.

Comment: The apps come from the enterprise applications, you can also register a custom app there or enable an app

Comment: Can't seem to add the apps I want to block. For instance, I want to block Telegram web. It appears in the Cloud App discovery, but can't be added to CA.

Comment: May I suggest another solution? I would use Azure Firewall Premium with web content filtering. Then you can redirect the network traffic through Azure Firewall and just add the urls you want to block. Or a open source solution like opnsense which you use as a gateway, and route the traffic through opnsense and block the urls and ips of telegram web.

Comment: I will also add a PowerShell script to create an app and create an ca policy